# enable buttons/input area upon condition jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, button

I am struggling to figure out how to enable a text box upon a certain condition. So, in the following example, I want the input box "name" to be disabled until the button "enterName" is clicked. Then when something is entered into the input box "name" I want the "useName" button to become enabled (or just pop up an alert box that says "enter a name")

```
<button id="enterName"> Enter a Name </button>
Name: <input type="text" id="name" disabled="disabled"/>
<button id="useName" disabled="disabled"> Use this name </button>
```

Right now, I have this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("button:#enterName").click(function(){

       /* ??? */

     });
    });

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button:#useName").click(function(){

    $("div.nameUsing").append($('input#name').val());
    $('input#name').val("");   //reset input field

 });
});
```

I don't know how to enable the text box the "enterName" button, or how to check for input when the "useName" button is pressed. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the [`.prop()` jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to enable or disable a control.

Tested and [working](http://jsfiddle.net/GjdwN/1/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button#enterName").click(function () {
        $('input#name').prop('disabled', false);
    });
    $('input#name').change(function () {
        $("button#useName").prop('disabled', $(this).val().length === 0); //enable if length > 0, disable otherwise
    });
    $("button#useName").click(function () {
        $("div.nameUsing").append($('input#name').val());
        $('input#name').val("");   //reset input field
    });
});​
```

Comment: @dubyaa: Happy to help. One note that I apparently forgot to include in the answer is that your jQuery selectors contain `:` and really shouldn't in this case. You may encounter unexpected behavior by continuing to include them. Updated answer (and fiddle) to remove the `:` from the selectors.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`removeAttr`](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/). For example:

```
$("#enterName").click(function() {
    $('#name').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$("#enterName").click(function() {
   $('#name').prop('disabled', false);
})

$('#name').keyup(function(){
    $('#useName').prop('disabled', $(this).val().length == 0);
});​
```

[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vbBzj/)